# Cg Shaders Alpha Blending

Tags: opengl, shader, cg

I want to use Alpha Blending `(SRC_ALPHA, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, which basically is this:

```
frag_out.aaaa * frag.out + ((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) - frag_out.aaaa) * pixel_color
```

Let's say the pixel color already on screen is `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`
The color I am currently rendering is `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4)`

When I render this the resulting color on screen has an alpha 0.76 (even though it was fully opaque BEFORE)

Indeed:

```
(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4) * (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4) + (0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6) * (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.76)
```

So basically the color on the screen was opaque (white) and after I put a transparent sprite on top the screen become transparent (0.76 alpha) and I am able to look through the background. It would be perfect if I could blend it like this:

```
(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1.0) * (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4) + (0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6) * (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Is it possible to achieve this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly possible when using OpenGL 3.0 and above since the blend functions can there be set separately for RGB and A. For your case this would be

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SOURCE_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SOURCE_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

The last parameter specifying the blend factor for destination alpha might have to be adapted since you didn't specify the behavior for destination alpha < 1. For more details have a look at the [function documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlendFuncSeparate.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to specify this type of blending in CG Shading language?

Comment: Sorry, never used CG.